# Can I have BindingAdapters with overlapping value sets?

Tags: android, android-databinding

Let's say I have this view model with methods:

```
public int getValueA() {
    return a;
}

public int getValueB() {
    return b;
}

@BindingAdapter("valueA")
public void setupSomething(View view, int valueA) {
    // do something with a
}

@BindingAdapter({"valueA", "valueB"})
public void setupSomethingElse(View view, int valueA, int valueB) {
    // do something with a and b
}
```

and I bind this to a view:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    bind:valueA="@{viewmodel.valueA}"
    bind:valueB="@{viewmodel.valueB}"/>
```

How can I call both `BindingAdapter` methods? Right now data binding is just calling the later. I guess I could just call `setSomething` from within `setSomethingElse` but this smells a little fishy to me (and partially defeats the purpose of databinding).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's like you're suggesting yourself: you need to call `setupSomething()` from `setupSomethingElse`. It's just fine doing so and how databindings work. **Only the best fitting `@BindingAdapter` will be used for your attributes.**

Alternatively you can use the [`requireAll()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/BindingAdapter.html#requireAll()) field of `@BindingAdapter`. But this is only feasible if you can handle the Java default value (in your case 0) for your values.

> Whether every attribute must be assigned a binding expression or if some can be absent. When this is false, the `BindingAdapter` will be called when at least one associated attribute has a binding expression. The attributes for which there was no binding expression (even a normal XML value) will cause the associated parameter receive the Java default value. Care must be taken to ensure that a default value is not confused with a valid XML value.

```
@BindingAdapter({"valueA", "valueB"}, requireAll = false)
public void setupSomethingElse(View view, int valueA, int valueB) {
    if (valueA != 0) {
        // do something with a
        if (valueB != 0) {
            // do something with a and b
        }
    }
}
```

So you don't need `setupSomething()` anymore. But personally I like the first approach better.